# MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, request-mapping, path-variables

I try to delete a user by getting id in url with an error:

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int'; 
nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
```

I change int id to String id, but then `deleteMyUser()` will not work because it accepts an integer.

Code:

```
<a href="/delete-user?id=${user.id}">x</a>


@RequestMapping("/delete-user{id}")
    public  String deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") int id,HttpServletRequest request)
    {   
        request.setAttribute("mode","MODE_HOME");
        userService.deleteMyUser(id);

        return "welcome";

    }
```

Comment: Check which is the value of id parameter in the html page (by viewing the source of the html page) it might be that in the url of the `a` tag the id is not a number

Comment: The value is valid

Comment: then keep the `a` tag like this `<a href="/delete-user?id=${user.id}">x</a>` and change `@RequestMapping("/delete-user{id}")` to `@RequestMapping("/delete-user")` and `@PathVariable("id")` to `@RequestParam("id")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `id` to **path**, so remove `?id=`:

```
<a href="/delete-user${user.id}">x</a>
```

Comment: how can i add more than one variable?

Comment: @K.Nehe usually you separate them with slashes as `/{id}/{otherId}`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are confusing between "query parameter" and "path variable"

```
<a href="/delete-user?id=${user.id}">x</a> // Passing value as query param


@RequestMapping("/delete-user{id}") // Expecting Path variable
```

To Fix this, either change both to query param or path variable (here I changed to path variable):

```
<a href="/delete-user/${user.id}">x</a>



@RequestMapping("/delete-user/{id}")
    public  String deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") int id,HttpServletRequest request)
    {   
        request.setAttribute("mode","MODE_HOME");
        userService.deleteMyUser(id);

        return "welcome";

    }
```

Comment: Your right- issue was with query param and path variable confusion

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain you some urls and there mapping

First /user/{id}/{userId} this is path variable format  /user?id=1&userid=2  this is requestparam/query param format.

```
https://domainname.com/find/user?id=1

@GetMapping("/find/user")
public  String deleteUser(@RequestParam("id") int id){   

}

https://domainname.com/find/user/1

@GetMapping("/find/user/{id}")
public  String deleteUser(@Pathvariable("id") int id){   

}

https://domainname.com/find/user/1/2
@GetMapping("/find/user/{id}/{userid}")
public  String deleteUser(@Pathvariable("id") int id,@Pathvariable("userId") 
int userId){   

}
```

** in case of pathvariable your variable are part of mapping

POST request

```
https://domainname.com/find/user
in request body {"id":1}

@PostMapping("/find/user")
public  String deleteUser(@RequestBody Integer id){   

}
https://domainname.com/find/user/1?userId=2
@GetMapping("/find/user/{id}")
public  String deleteUser(@Pathvariable("id") int id,@RequestParam("userId") 
int userId){   

}
```

if you are using `@RequestMapping` then its recommanded to define method also by default it map with get request.

`@RequestMapping(method = [RequestMethod.GET])`

Comment: Thanks i've understood

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
 RequestMapping("/delete-user/{id}")
```

Use a slash between delete-user and id and then call

```
<a href="/delete-user/${user.id}">x</a>
```

Also ensure that ${user.id} contains a valid number value

Comment: Does not work the issue is i was confusing query param and path variable